# At what point on the graph of $y=\frac{1}{2}x^2$ is the tangent line parallel to the line $2x-4y=3$

Tags: calculus

I found the slope of the second equation to be $x\over 2$, and the derivative of the first
 equation is simply $x$, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

So your function is $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^2$.  Note that its derivative, $f'$, will give the slope of the tangent line at any point you wish by simply plugging in for $x$.  Indeed, you have calculated the derivative correctly.

Now what is the slope of the line $2x-4y = 3$?  For what $x$ does the derivative of your function equal this slope?

Once you have found this $x$, then plug it back into your original function to get the appropriate $y$-value, and hence, the point on the graph.

Comment: The slope of the line is $1/2x$ I think. Which are you considering the original equation?

Comment: Close!  Once you have your line in the form $y = mx + b$, the slope of your line will be the coefficient on $x$, which is just $\frac{1}{2}$.  So we are looking for a tangent line to the graph with a slope of $\frac{1}{2}$.  Can you deduce what the x-coordinate on the graph would need to be using what you've calculated with your derivative?

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of $f(x) = \frac12x^2$ is $x$.

The slope of the line $2x - 4y = 3$ is $\frac12$.

The tangent line will be parallel at that point, where the derivative(slope) is $\frac12$, because lines with the same slope are parallel.
So the point will be $x = \boxed{\frac12}$